# JQuery $.get unusual return data

Tags: jquery, ubuntu

I'm trying to pull some data from a file using the $.get method but all I get is this:

```
undefined slope
undefined reference to
undefined
undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
undefined symbols for architecture i386
```

The code:

```
$.get('inc/autocomplete.php?q=' + $('.searchbox').val(), function(data){
      $('.autocomplete').html(data);  
});
```

I recently moved to Ubuntu and I think that that's the problem. Opening autocomplete.php in the browser gives correct results. Any suggestions?

Comment: if it works in the browser, what's the problem?  Does jQuery work outside of a browser?

Comment: Are you using `$.post`, or `$.get`. your title says `$.get`, but your code says `$.post`. This problem is most likely with your php code, not jQuery or ubuntu.

Comment: @KevinB I corrected it, and as I said, opening autocomplete.php directly in the browser gives the expected results, opening autocomplete.php with the get method gives the results that I posted above

Comment: Right, but the weird text you are getting is coming from php (or your webserver), not jQuery. Most likely the content being passed to php (`$('.searchbox').val()`) isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: You're correct! searchbox is an ID not a class, how stupid of me.